# Recovering transactions from ldb files

Tags: go-ethereum, recovery, leveldb

I have a geth-based ethereum installation that started crashing with "Missing trie node" errors. In the chaindata folder I have hundreds of `ldb` files, nearly all of which are around 2.1Mb - but the most recent one, started yesterday, is 151Mb, suggesting something has gone astray in it. It then turns out that transactions were not syncing to other nodes in my network, so this is my only copy of the data. The corrupted file means that `geth` will not start, but that also means that the other (non-corrupted) transactions in older files are inaccessible.

How can I recover those transactions? Can I import individual `ldb` files directly into a new setup rather than the whole chain data folder? Can I remove the problem file without breaking things too much?

Answer (score -1):

You're hosed. Delete the data folder and re-sync. Be super, super, extra, extra careful not to delete your key files.

Comment: That's the problem - there is nowhere to resync from. I couldn't help but notice the comment on the LevelDB wikipedia page: "LevelDB is widely noted for being unreliable and databases it manages are prone to corruption". Doesn't seem like a great base to build on.

Comment: You're talking about `geth` right?  If you see the files, you know where the folder is. Find instructions elsewhere for deleting the database folder. The next time you start geth it will re-sync. I won't give specific instructions because I don't want blame if you delete your private keys and lose your money. Look for a good set of instructions that explain what that means.

Comment: Do you have a single blockchain node running a private chain? Because that's the only time you'd have nowhere to resync from.

Comment: I am unsure how useful this is as an answer :P